# Unable to locate package winehq-stable on 22.04

Tags: wine

Trying to install Wine following the instructions on the site, but there is no `winehq-stable` package. I tried installing `winehq-staging` and it worked fine.

Pop!_OS 22.04

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't have `winehq`, just [wine](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=jammy&section=all&arch=any&keywords=wine&searchon=names). Not sure about POS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm having the same issue and I found out that you can't install winehq-**stable** on 22.04 because the packages were not built for 22.04 yet.

Check out this link:
https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-amd64/

It doesn't have stable release yet (as of the time of writing) but it does have staging and devel, that's why you can install winehq-staging fine. Devel should also install fine.

I'm not sure if those are automated builds and we'll need to wait until next stable release or something failed.

For now you can install wine from Ubuntu packages instead of winehq but you will get an older version of wine (6.0 if I remember right). You can also keep using winehq-staging until stable is built.

Comment: As of May 15 it is still only listing `winehq-devel` and `winehq-staging`

Comment: As of August 21 it is still the case

Comment: As per their doc, winehq-stable will be available once they release 7.0.1 version: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu#Ubuntu_22.04_and_Wine_stable